# secure log in and session management for iphone app

Tags: iphone, c++, c, cocoa, ios

I have a server (**not** a web server but just low level tcp socket server), and I want to know how to log in securely through iphone (probably using ssl), manage session and communicate with the server(probably using aes). My idea is "use ssl to log in and exchange aes key" and "use that aes key to communicate later." Someone has any better idea? Please provide me with some sample code to do such stuffs.

Comment: +1 for asking code. Usually that's a -1, but not in this area. Encryption is just too hard to get right; there are no minor bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [CFReadStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) and [CFWriteStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001447). You can setup SSL Connections with the CFStream types as well.

To setup an SSL connection you need somthing similar to this:

```
NSString *host = @"example.com";
unsigned port = 1234;
CFReadStreamRef     readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef    writeStream;

CFHostRef remoteHost = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                            (CFStringRef) host);

//Create a socket pair for reading and writing
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                     remoteHost, 
                                     port, 
                                     &readStream, 
                                     &writeStream);

//Setup ssl properties - Customize it to yout needs
NSDictionary *sslProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                (NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL, kCFStreamSSLLevel, 
                                   kCFBooleanTrue, kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                                   kCFBooleanFalse, kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                                   kCFNull, kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                                   kCFBooleanFalse, kCFStreamSSLIsServer,
                                   nil];

CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, 
                        kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, 
                        sslProperties);

CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, 
                         kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, 
                         sslProperties);    


CFStreamClientContext readContext = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
CFOptionFlags registeredReadEvents = kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable 
                                    | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred 
                                    | kCFStreamEventEndEncountered 
                                    | kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted;


//replace OnReadStreamEvent with your own callback
if(CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream, registeredReadEvents, OnReadStreamEvent, &readContext)) {
    CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
}

CFStreamClientContext writeContext = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
CFOptionFlags registeredWriteEvents = kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes 
                                        | kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred 
                                        | kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted;

//replace OnWriteStreamEvent with your own callback
if(CFWriteStreamSetClient(writeStream, registeredWriteEvents, OnWriteStreamEvent, &writeContext)) {
    CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(writeStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
}
```

That's the part the might be hard to figure out from the documentation. Maybe this helps you to get started.

Comment: A c++ alternative might be Boost.Asio